# Why is coconut oil healthier when it has so much saturated fat?

Tags: biochemistry, food, diet

I noticed that coconut oil has ~96% saturated fat, and I was under the assumption that saturated fats = bad for health.

Why is it that coconut oil is healthier to alternatives with much less saturated fat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

coconut oil is composed mainly of medium-chain triglycerides, 1)it is smaller than other long-chain triglycerides so that it can be digested easily, 2)the digestion of coconut oil does not involve in the Pancreatic digestive enzyme system, 3) liver prefer use medium-chain triglycerides as the fuel sources 4) medium-chain triglycerides will convert to monoglyceride and medium-chain fatty acid which have strong antibacterial