# Nonpancreatic digestion of tryglicerides

Tags: biochemistry, physiology, food, human-physiology, digestive-system

In [an answer about coconut oil](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/23161/33294) I can read

> the digestion of coconut oil does not involve in the Pancreatic digestive enzyme system

In both primary and secondary school I have learned that fat needs to be processed by pancreatic lipase as tryglicerides can not be absorbed.

Are medium-chain tryglicerides an exception (they can be absorbed), are there other (nonpancreatic) lipases in human digestion system, or is the linked answer wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities concerning the further metabolism of MCTs: the glycerides are absorbed and *immediately* transported through the portal vein to the liver whereupon they are oxidised to release energy. 
Alternatively, dependent on the size of the MCT, ranging from hexanoic acid tails to dodecanoic acid tails, it may undergo the standard catalysis by pancreative lipase to form monoglycerides, diglycerides and free fatty acids.

More information regarding the physiological effects of middle-chain fatty acids may be available from: https://academic.oup.com/jn/article/132/3/329/4687297